# AngularJS Bootstrap UI Automatic Date Conversion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I'm currently using the 0.14.3 version of AngularUI

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.3/

I'm having a bit of an issue with the datepickers. I have this so far:

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="fooDate"/>
```

with the Calendar, and so far it works just fine. The dates are stored in this format:

2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

The problem is that the database (which is unchangeable, I've already tried to convince them to change it) takes what comes from the input box and truncates it into a string that looks like 2016-01-01, which is saved into the database. So when I save, quit, and then load the form and it retrieves information from the backend, it retrieves 2016-01-01 as the ng-model. In the eyes of uib-datepicker-popup version 0.14.3, this is not a valid date format.

I've written a directive to automatically convert 2016-01-01 but I don't know how to finish it, since changing the ng-model to new Date(stringDate) where var stringDate = '2016-01-01' displays

```
Fri Jan 01 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

In the input box.

So I was wondering how I would be able to convert a String 2016-01-01 into a date object for the ng-model in

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="fooDate"/>
```

Which would allow it to both display

```
01/01/2016 in the input box (because of the format of datepicker) *and* be valid.
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$scope.fooDate=new Date($scope.fooDate)`isn't enought ?
or `new Date($scope.fooDate).toISOString()`

Comment: Ah I nearly forgot about this. Thanks for your suggestions! Originally I was using new Date(2015-03-03) to parse it but it'd display the date object as 2015-03-02 due to localizing the timezone. I eventually used moment.js to get what i wanted. moment(2015-03-03).toDate()